# Dynamically change page content but also access content with URL hash

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, reactjs

I want users to be able to change page contents without having to load a new HTML page. I used the ng-click, ng-show, and ng-hide components from angular.js to change the visible content ([example pen](http://codepen.io/mhancock/pen/VjvaQE)), but it's not quite what I need.

I need users to be able to swap content on one page, but also access either piece of content with a direct URL, which isn't possible with my existing code.

For example, if the page URL is `example.com/git` by default I want the "Commands" content to display. However, if users enter a URL like `example.com/git#terms` then I want the terms content to display.

### Example

[Here's an example of exactly what I want to do](https://www.atlassian.com/git/glossary). When users click "Terminology" the page looks like it just swaps out the content, but the URL changes. Users can go directly to "Terminology" with this url: `https://www.atlassian.com/git/glossary/terminology`.

I *think* that page is using react, but is there a simpler way to do this? I'm pretty new to scripting, so I'd really appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: Rather than showing/hiding elements based on a ng-click. Look into using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). Then you can define states that can be linked to using a #

Comment: Personally I'd use ngRoute and $routeProvider in `app.config()` to set this kind of logic, but for a more heavy duty approach then ui-router is the go-to solution

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your controller:

```
$scope.showme = location.href.indexOf("#terms") != -1;
```

What this does is to set the `showme` variable to `true` if the current URL contains `#terms`.